# Xcode 4 preferences pane is missing the "Source Trees" tab?

Tags: xcode, tabs, tree, preferences

I'm working on a project where I need to bring in an outside library.

I found the library, and in order to make it a part of my project, my understanding is that I need to take the project provided (which includes the library I want) and then set the HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS to an appropriate value to be able to find the new library.

However whenever I try, I found that the "Source Trees" tab is missing from my XCode preferences pane.  Does anybody have any idea why this might be?  It feels very strange.  Should I try downloading the program again?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Under the preferences pane in Xcode 4 and Xcode 5 you can go to the "Locations" tab then select the "Source Trees" option from the segmentation control on that tab.

Additionally, if you want to add something that's not shared for a single project, you can select your project then select the "Build Settings" tab and search for `header search` in the filter/search box at the top to find the project's "Header Search Paths" setting.

Comment: Looked into the Source Trees feature and found it. I've updated my answer.

Comment: I did end up finding it soon after, thank you.  I just couldn't find anywhere that let me know where it was.

Answer (score 0):

It seams that `Source Trees` was renamed to `Custom Paths`

```
Xcode -> Preferences... -> Locations -> Custom Paths
```

[image]